# while saving from data gridview the same thing getting saved multiple times in vb.net application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a grid view like this: i am working on vb.net windows application
[image]

in load event i given code like this:

```
Dim cd As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
        adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select c.cid,c.CompanyName as Company,d.dtId,d.dtName as Department,d.dtPhone as D.phone,d.dtEmail as D.mail from CompanyMaster_tbl c join  DepartmentMaster_tbl d on c.Cid=d.cId", con.connect)
        dt1 = New DataTable
        bSource = New BindingSource
        adapter.Fill(dt1) 'Filling dt with the information from the DB
        bSource.DataSource = dt1
        gv.DataSource = bSource
        gv.Columns("cid").Visible = False
        gv.Columns("dtId").Visible = False
```

in save button i given code like this:

```
Dim sqlInsertT1 As String = ""
        Dim sqlInsertT2 As String = ""
        For i As Integer = 0 To gv.RowCount - 2
            If gv.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value IsNot System.DBNull.Value Then

                sqlInsertT1 = "Insert Into CompanyMaster_tbl(CompanyName) Values ('" + gv.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value + "')"
                Exetransaction(sqlInsertT1)
                Ccid = RecordID("Cid", "CompanyMaster_tbl", "CompanyName", gv.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)
            End If

            sqlInsertT2 = "Insert Into DepartmentMaster_tbl(dtname,dtphone,dtEmail,Cid) Values ('" + gv.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value + "','" + gv.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value + "','" + gv.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value + "'," & Ccid & ");"
            Exetransaction(sqlInsertT2)
        Next
```

in this case firs I added three department under the company IBS,then i saved.first time everything saved correct. again i run the application,and added one more department,phone,mail under the comapny IBS. then i clicked save button..but again the same department getting saved..   ( i dont want save all department again,i only want to save last added department,phone,email) ..so what i have to change in my code

Comment: Don't concatonate for sql query. Use Parameters (ex: SqlParameters). You could get sql injected if there's a string with a '

Answer (score 0):

As you have bound to `dt1` in you given code you can look at `dt1.GetChanges()` to look at just what has changed if this is what you are after.

Alternatively I would suggest making the DataGrid read only and then have a new form for editing or adding a Department or Company. This gives far greater control but is only an option if you are in a position to make the DataGrid read only.

Comment: sir i cant make datagrid readonly,,in datagrid i have to edit,add and delete